# Should Comments be Repeated if the Same Code is Repeated in the Same File?

Tags: comments

If I am reusing the same code in multiple places/functions in the same file, should I put the same comments over and over or just once? Does the protocol/standard coding practice for comments change with each language?

Comment: Y do you have repeated code in the same file. That itself is not a good practice.

Comment: I understand that you are not supposed to make redundant code, and that's not really what I am referring to. For example, if you have multiple functions that do something after opening a file, should I have comments explaining what is happening each time each function opens the file or closes the file for that matter?

Comment: @Denzil See, the comment above. Also, are there aspects of the code that should or shouldn't be commented according to standard practice?

Comment: there should be minimal comments, your code should be self-explanatory. comments should explain the How, not the What.

Answer (score 3):

[Mu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(negative)). You shouldn't be repeating code like that at all. Refactor it into a function so you only need to write it once.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the protocol/standard coding practice for comments change with each language?

Not really, I have programmed in multiple languages and my comment-mentality hasn't changed.

> If I am reusing the same code in multiple places/functions in the same file, should I put the same comments over and over or just once?
>
> should I have comments explaining what is happening each time each function opens the file or closes the file for that matter?

You should only comment out what isn't explicit in your code. If in your code, you repeat the same block of code in multiple places, then this isn't good practice and you should use *functions*(as @Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica said) to put your repeated code in statement blocks, to then reuse it by calling the function. Also if you are repeating the code of one function in another, remember that you can call a function from inside the other function to avoid **code duplication**. So if you do the latter then you can just comment what the main function does and when a user see's that function for instance in another function, he can go back in your code and check the comment for the original function.

> Also, are there aspects of the code that should or shouldn't be commented according to standard practice?

Again only comment what is not explicit in your code, if you have a function for instance that just displays a text, then that won't need a comment, but if at the contrary your code uses external dependencies or your own classes then a good practice would be to comment what is their role in your code; essentially explaining how your code utilizes these resources.